# Underdamped RLC with CCCS, calculating capacitor voltage

Tags: current-source, passive-networks, step-response

Referring to "Electrical Circuits" Nilsson/Riedel 10th Edition.

[image]

I have a classic underdamped RLC circuit with a CCCS (Current Controlled Current Source) with a current multiplication factor of \$\beta\$. I want to find \$V_c(t)\$

In the attempt I end up with this equation:
\$LC \frac{d^{2}  V_c}{dt^{2}} + RC \frac{dv_{c}}{dt} + \frac{V_c}{\beta} = V\beta\$

which doesn't look like equation 8.66 in the book which is for RLC without a CCCS:
\$\frac{d^{2}  V_c}{dt^{2}} + \frac{R}{L}  \frac{dv_c}{dt} + \frac{V_c}{LC} = \frac{V}{LC}\$

So I'm a little bit at a loss in how to find the solutions from here.

Updated:

Going way back in my notes I (re)discovered that
\$\beta=e^{V} = 1+\frac{V}{V_c}\$

Which now gives me this equation
\$LC \frac{d^{2}  V_c}{dt^{2}} + RC \frac{dv_{c}}{dt} + \frac{V^2_c}{V_c\ V+V^2} = \frac{V\ V_c}{V+V_c}\$

But now I'm stuck again

Comment: Define your CCCS formula.

Comment: @Andyaka My best guess would be \$i_{out}=\beta i_{in}\$ but it gives me headaches because there is only one loop.

Comment: Maybe the question is about a VCCS with Vc as the input.

Comment: try this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit  see derivation as it relates to  ω²=1/LC & time constant τ=L/R the exponential envelope

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I'm sorry but I'm math dyslexic, so it's not obvious to me what you are getting at, can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: If Wiki can't , nor can I

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I tried the Wiki article but found it too eclectic, then I tried [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/ee-circuit-analysis-topic/ee-natural-and-forced-response/a/ee-rlc-natural-response-derivation) which was erroneous (decay envelope is only dependent on time). Both sources seem to use the book I referenced so I'm using that now.

Comment: Better go back and learn the basics https://www.d.umn.edu/~snorr/ece2006s4/Lab8a.PDF